# PDE Transport Equation(?) with Decay and Forcing Term

Tags: partial-differential-equations, forcing, boundary-value-problem

So I am kind of lost on how to solve this PDE IVP.

$${\mathrm du \over \mathrm dt}+2{\mathrm du \over \mathrm dx}+4u=x$$ where $t>0$ and $x$ is in $R$, with the initial condition $u(x,0)=uo(x)=e^x$

Then consider the case for $x$ is contained in $[-1,1]$ boundary. Specify which boundary point is the inflow and solve the problem with the boundary condition $\phi (inflow,t)=e^t$.

So I normally know how to solve ${\mathrm du \over \mathrm dt}+2{\mathrm du \over \mathrm dx}+4u=x$ but I'm kinda confused on how to do it when it equals a nonconstant. Do I try ${\mathrm du \over \mathrm dt}+2{\mathrm du \over \mathrm dx}=x-4u$$?

Please help!!!

Comment: What is uo(x) in the second line?

Comment: I think they meant $u_0\left(x\right)$ (i.e. some smooth function).

Comment: The tag "forcing" does not refer to forced motion is a diff eq, it refers to a logic technique used to prove, for example, that the Continuum Hypothesis is undecidable in the context of the usual arithmetic axioms.  So I would suggest removing that tag, if somebody can do so.

Answer (score 1):

To make the problem simpler, let $v\left(x,t\right)=e^{2x}u\left(x,t\right)$
so that

$$
u_{t}+2u_{x}+4u=e^{-2x}v_{t}+2\left(-2e^{-2x}v+e^{-2x}v_{x}\right)+4e^{-2x}v=e^{-2x}\left(v_{t}+2v_{x}\right)
$$

and hence we look for a function $v$ s.t.

$$
\left\langle 1,2\right\rangle \cdot\nabla v=e^{2x}x.
$$

You should now be able to apply the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Characteristics_of_first-order_partial_differential_equation) for a first order PDE and use the relationship between $v$ and $u$ to find an expression for $u$.

Comment: So I tried doing that kind of transformation, but I still ran into problems. I compared (dv/dt)+2(dv/dx)=x(e^2x) with the Lagrange (dv/dt)=(dv/dt)+(dv/dx)(dx/dt) and I got (dx/dt)=2 and eventually got x(o)=x-2t, no problem. Then I tried differentiating (dv/dt)=x(e^2x) and I got v=(xt)(e^2x). When I tried to go from v's to u's I got that u=xt. So is my answer then u=(xt)(e^(x-2t))?? Because when I tried plugging that back into the original equation, I did not end up with x...

Comment: Keep at it, I guess. Be careful with your work.