# Possible applications for this semi-linear first order PDE.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, soft-question, applications

I am cross-posting this question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/590549/possible-applications-for-this-semi-linear-first-order-pde

First of all I should say that I work in probability and my knowledge about PDEs is quite small, so this question could make little sense, please let me know if something is not well stated.

While dealing with approximations methods for SDEs a I've noticed a particular connection between an SDE and a deterministic PDE of the form:

$$\partial_t u+\sigma(t)\partial_x u=b(t,x,u)$$
where $b$ is a Lipschitz continuous function in $u$.

I've tried searching online for application of this kind of equation but unfortunately I wasn't able to find anything concrete.
In the book by  Moussiaux, Zaitsev and Polyanin "Handbook of first order PDEs" they discuss methods for solving this kind of equations but they don't provide examples of applications.

I suspect this could be connected somehow to the transport equations, but I am not entirely sure.
Do you know of some references for applications of this particular equation?

Comment: The transport equation with forcing and damping is probably a good example.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1005128/pde-transport-equation-with-decay-and-forcing-term

Comment: @K.defaoite Thanks! I'll search more online about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation is quasilinear, but sometimes it can be connected with a semilinear equation
$$ v_s +v_x = c(s,x,v). $$
Specifically, define $\Sigma(t) = \int_0^t \sigma (\tau)d\tau$.
If $\Sigma$ is an invertible function, for example if $\sigma$
is increasing, then the change of variables
$$ s = \Sigma(t), \qquad u(x,t) = v(x,s) $$
gives
$$ u_t+\sigma u_x = \sigma(v_s+v_x) = b(\Sigma^{-1}(s),x,v) $$
so dividing by $\sigma$ you have $v_x+v_x = c(s,x,v)$ with
$$c(s,x,v) = \frac{b(\Sigma^{-1}(s),x,v)}{\Sigma'(\Sigma^{-1}(s))}$$

Edit: for an example application, suppose $w(x,t)$ is the
depth of a layer of particles that are being transported to the right
by some process, or perhaps the density of animals at longitude $x$ during
an eastward migration. Consider a conservation law of the form
$$
 \frac{d}{dt}\int_a^{a+h} w(x,t)dx
 = kw(a,t)-kw(a+h,t)
 +\int_a^{a+h}c(w,x,t)dx
$$
where some function $c(w,x,t)$ represents a source of particles/length, or
a birth rate of animals, and $kw$ is the flux of particles from left
to right, $k$ being a fraction of the local density that are able
to migrate past.

Thus the conservation law says that the time rate of change of the population
in the interval $[a,a+h]$ is given by flux in (imigration), minus
flux out (emigration), plus
the birth rate.

Divide by $h$ and take the limit as $h$ tends to zero; you get by the
Fundamental Theorem of Calculus that
$$
 w_t = -kw_x+c(w,x,t).
$$

Comment: interesting, still do you know some applications for this equations, i.e. are they somehow interesting besides the purely mathematical aspect?

Comment: I've added an application in an edit.